# when storing a large positive integer it is converting to different negative number

Tags: c

When i storing a large positive integer in unsigned long int in c, then it unknowingly converting to negative number.

for example

```
 a=2075000020, b=100000000,here a+b=-2119967266.
```

Please help me understand.

Comment: Could not replicate: http://ideone.com/l9VTwa
Are you sure you're using `unsigned` for `a`, `b`, and the result?  How are you printing the result?

Comment: Please show a small test program that exhibits the problem. My guess is that you're not printing the value correctly. Use `"%lu"` to print an `unsigned long` value; `"%ld"` is for *`signed`* `long`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have been printing an unsigned integer, because it has printed a *sign*. Even if you declare the variable as `unsigned`, once it is on the stack for `printf()` to use, it is interpreted as a binary value to be used as specified by the format in `printf()`.

Note the difference between these, and the results. In the the third example, you can see that bit 31 is set, which is the sign bit for `signed long int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    unsigned long int a=2075000020, b=100000000, c;
    c = a + b;
    printf ("Signed %ld\n", c);
    printf ("Unsigned %lu\n", c);
    printf ("Hexadecimal 0x%lX\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Signed -2119967276
Unsigned 2175000020
Hexadecimal 0x81A3DDD4
```